# Reinitializing a json variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

If I have a json object in javascript that already has its members set to values, is there a simple way to reinitialize the members to some default (null) without having to expressly set each of the members. Example:

```
var json = 
          {
            "Name": "John",
            "Age": 25
          }
```

After initializing:

```
var json = 
          {
            "Name": null,
            "Age": null
          }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a flat structure for your json object (eg, no nested objects where you want to maintain that nested structure), you can do this:

```
for (var key in json) { json[key] = null; }
```

Update: To handle nesting, this may work...

```
function reinit_json(json) {
    for (var key in json) {
        if (json[key] != null && typeof json[key] == 'object')
            reinit_json(json[key]);
        else
            json[key] = null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Except I made my example simple. In reality it has many nested levels.

Comment: +1. Just add a check if(json.hasOwnProperty(key)). The if block is optional if you know for sure that nothing is every going to extend Object.prototype.